# Stripe Integration With Firebase on iOS

Tags: ios, rest, firebase, stripe-payments

I'm building an iOS application using Firebase as my backend and want to implement Stripe without an external server. 
I've already checked out this post: [Firebase payment gateways?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879095/firebase-payment-gateways/22969974#22969974) — and it shows the following process regarding Stripe's payment process/gateway:

1. User initiates transaction on your site
2. Client code sends them to Stripe to enter their CC info
3. Client code obtains a token representing the secure transaction
4. **A server process is notified by stripe when the transaction is validated**
5. **The server submits the payment authorization with the token**
6. **Stripe sends a transaction receipt to the server process** or Zapier, which would be stored back in Firebase

**I've already contacted Firebase** regarding Zapier and they told me that Zapier doesn't support this process anymore.
Also: Unlike Braintree, which requires to generate a token server-side, Stripe's key is associated with my account.

Theoretically then, I would be able to integrate Stripe with no external server using Firebase's REST API, correct?

> We can use any Firebase Realtime Database URL as a REST endpoint. All we need to do is append .json to the end of the URL and send a request from our favorite HTTPS client.
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 4, 5 and ~6 still require a server-side application running one of [Stripe's API libraries](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries) or one of their [third-party integrations](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations).

6 seems to be describing webhooks, and it ***might*** be possible to just wire [Stripe webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) right up to a [Firebase 'save' URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data), but ultimately you need some kind of application to process the charges on a server.

Comment: Thanks @floatingLomas ! I think there also might be a different way to approach this, take a look at Fabric [link](https://stripe.com/blog/stripe-on-fabric) . They have an out of the box solution for stripe...This shouldn't require any server to work. Would really appreciate your input :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) Actually, it does - it's a client-side toolkit, but it does still require server-side code.  If you scroll down to 'next steps' [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/stripe/features) you'll see it talks about building your server-side application.  If you don't want to build that out, there are a bunch of [third-party integrations](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations) available for Stripe, and one of those might fit your usecase!

Answer (score 1):

For many use cases, you can now integrate Stripe with Firebase without the need to build out a separate backend. See the [Run Payments with Stripe](https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments) Firebase Extension.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to indicate that firebase now supports stripe payments without an external server:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments

They have some sample code and instructions here:  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe