# Stripe Integration in Android, what to do after?

Tags: android, firebase, stripe-payments, credit-card

I'm developing a credit card payment using Stripe. After creating a Token (which I've done yet), I don't know how to go on.

Official documentation says:

> **Using tokens**
>
> Using the payment token, however it was obtained, requires an API call from your server using your secret API key. (For security purposes, you should never embed your secret API key in your app.)
> Set up an endpoint on your server that can receive an HTTP POST call for the token. In the onActivityResult method (for Android Pay) or the onSuccess callback (when using your own form), you’ll need to POST the supplied token to your server. Make sure any communication with your server is SSL secured to prevent eavesdropping.
> Take a look at the full example application to see everything put together.

And my code is:

```html
public class FragmentThree extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "FragmentThree";
    //Stripe
    private Card card;

    private TextView mResponse;
    private Button mPaymentBtn;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);

        mResponse = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.response);
        mPaymentBtn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.paymentBtn);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        mPaymentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(isNetworkAvailable()){

                    String cardNumber = "4242-4242-4242-4242";
                    int cardExpMonth = 12;
                    int cardExpYear = 2018;
                    String cardCVC = "123";

                    card = new Card( //We create a new Card
                            cardNumber,
                            cardExpMonth,
                            cardExpYear,
                            cardCVC
                    );

                    if (!card.validateCard()){ //The card is not a valid one

                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.Not_Valid_Card, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{

                        Stripe stripe = null;

                        try {

                            //TODO Change with LIVE KEY
                            stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_wt0efdvgYxds7CywHYKCqnhX");

                        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {

                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    R.string.Merchant_Does_Not_Exist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        if(stripe != null){

                            stripe.createToken(
                                    card,
                                    new TokenCallback() {
                                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                                            // Send token to your server

                                            Log.d(TAG, "The token number is: " + token.getId());
                                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                                            // Show localized error message
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                                    error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                            );
                        }


                    }
                }else{

                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            R.string.No_Internet_Connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

How to let a Server (which I don't own) know about my Token? And what to do after that? How to make an API call from the Server or Firebase?
I can use Firebase: Do I have to use It? And what do I have to implement there?

Server side, for me, represents a problem.

Can someone write me a step by step implementation so that I Know how to handle tokens and what i can do next?

And how to be sure about SSL Security?

Sorry for my questions but I never did It before.

Thank you, Gaetano

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to POST that token to a server in the `onActivityResult` function: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android#using-tokens

You will definitely need a server-side application - or a third-party integration - to create Charges; you can't do that with Firebase as far as I know.  https://stripe.com/docs/charges

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediary server. I've done Stripe integrations with Heroku for $7/mo written in node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can't do stripe api payment in client side. You need to create a service with a method to handle stripe payment. And then pass the token which you got from token creation to that service.

your client side code -

```
stripe.createToken(
   card,
   new TokenCallback() {
   public void onSuccess(Token token) {
   // Send token to your server
```

example (node js service method) : -

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    var stripe = require("stripe")("your private key");

    // Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
    // Get the payment token submitted by the form:
    var token = request.body.stripeToken; // Using Express

    // Charge the user's card:
    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 1000,
      currency: "usd",
      description: "Example charge",
      source: token,
    }, function(err, charge) {
      // asynchronously called
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to send token to Firebase in some way using node.js? I really Thank you for the answer

Comment: According to your code you will receive the stripe token to "TokenCallback()" method. Then make a curl request to your service to do the payment. If it is Firebase please check this question too. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911456/stripe-integration-with-firebase-on-ios)

Comment: If you want you can use thrid party tool as well example - https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/stripe/